# Export to csv using FasterCSV causes strange punctuation characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I have a client that writes a daily feature menu in Word.  They then copy & paste out of Word into a Rails app that exports the menu into a csv file using FasterCSV.  The problem is that some punctuation gets messed up in the export.  I believe it may be an encoding problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here's an example:

Word version - Chef’s vegetables

After export - Chefâ€™s vegetables

Another example:

Word version - sautéed peppers

After export - sautÃ©ed peppers

Any ideas would be a huge help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word documents are not text documents. Things like smart-quotes, non-ASCII quotes, accented characters, etc. obviously get messed up. I'm not even sure if it's just a matter of UTF-8 encoding, although you could try that first--[see this for more info](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/). [FasterCSV supports Ruby 1.9 encoding vi the :encoding option](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html#M000021).

Personally, I tend to just tell people to not do that, and use an actual text editor, but that isn't always an option.

Comment: Interesting article! I may have to tell my client to be careful when copy & pasting.  I'll keep researching for more possible answers.